# Can one take "pre-op" medicine on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine

As an extension of [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25587/5275),

Can one take medication on Shabbat on preparation for a procedure that occurs the next day or in a few days?

For example, can one take:

- amoxicillin for oral surgery to be done the following Tuesday
- "goop" for a colonoscopy done on Sunday

In both cases, the doctor has prescribed the medication.

The linked question seems to address preventing a medical condition that is likely to occur on the same day. In the examples that I mentioned, there is no condition or illness that will occur. The "goop" is not to prevent an illness. It is to aid a procedure. Amoxicillin is taken to reduce the **possibility** of infection after the oral surgery. It is not certain that one may become infected without taking it, but the doctor is being safe.

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן שכח - דין חולה בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0086_L2) says that perfectly healthy people may take medicine. (As opposed to unwell people who may only do so under certain conditions.)

> **לז:** כָּל אֳכָלִים וּמַשְׁקִים שֶׁהֵם מַאֲכַל  בְּרִיאִים מֻתָּר לְאָכְלָן וְלִשְׁתּוֹתָן לִרְפוּאָה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהֵם קָשִׁים לִקְצָת בְּרִיאִים וּמוּכָחָא מִלְּתָא דְּלִרְפוּאָה עָבִיד, אֲפִלּוּ הָכֵי שָׁרֵי; וְ**כָל שֶׁאֵינוֹ מַאֲכָל וּמַשְׁקֵה בְּרִיאִים**, אָסוּר לְאָכְלוֹ וְלִשְׁתּוֹתוֹ לִרְפוּאָה. וְדַוְקָא מִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ מֵחוּשׁ בְּעָלְמָא וְהוּא מִתְחַזֵּק וְהוֹלֵךְ כְּבָרִיא, **אֲבָל אִם אֵין לוֹ שׁוּם מֵחוּשׁ, מֻתָּר**‏